# Object declarations: Do strings as keys make a difference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

There are some questions floating around here on stackoverflow about JSON being a subset of the Object Literal Notation. But I couldn't find an answer to a specific question of mine.

Is there any difference between

```
var obj = {keyName : "value"};
```

and

```
var obj = {"keyName" : "value"};
```

in JavaScript?

Comment: It is not "strings as keys". Keys are always strings. It's a notational matter of whether or not you quote them. A better title would be "Does quoting keys make a difference?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The difference is that the file size of the latter will be two bytes larger to account for the two extra `"` characters in your code.

Otherwise no, there's no difference between the two example objects you've given.

```
var obj = {keyName : "value"};

obj.keyName;       /* "value" */
obj["keyName"];    /* "value" */
```

```js
var obj = {"keyName" : "value"};

obj.keyName;       /* "value" */
obj["keyName"];    /* "value" */
```

Answer (score 5):

No difference, except that the 2nd one will add two extra `"` characters in your code which will cost you two extra bytes.

And the reason the two types of declaring object properties `with or without quotes is because`
You can try,

```
var obj = {"key Name" : "value"};
```

and still access it as

```
obj['key Name']
```

But not

```
var obj = {key Name : "value"};
```

Thinking this way, there is a difference

Comment: OP's question asks if there's a difference between `keyName` and `"keyName"`, not `key  Name` and `"key  Name"`.

Comment: While explaining what is the difference I need to explain why both kind of notations are used. anyways, thanks I am editing the answer.