# JavaScript JSON object with square brackets and quote

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = { first: 123, second: 456 };

console.log(arr['first']);            // 123
console.log(arr['second']);           // 456
console.log(arr.first);               // 123
console.log(arr['first', 'second']);  // 456
```

Problem 1: Why **arr['first', 'second']** will get last element?

Problem 2: What's different **['child']** and **.child** ?

---

Thx all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017571/object-declarations-do-strings-as-keys-make-a-difference/26017647#26017647

Comment: first, yout `arr` not an array, also see about [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) and [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: The two questions are both duplicates, but separate ones.

Comment: sorry @Grundy, I modify title now.

Comment: @Salmon what output you expect in this case `console.log(arr['first', 'second']);` :-)

Comment: @Grundy like [123, 456].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JS, objects are collections of key-value pairs (maps or dictionaries, if you want). An array is just another type of object. Your example however features a plain object.

Objects, as I said earlier, have keys, which are used to provide access to methods and properties.

```
var o = { 
  x: 12, 
  y: function () { console.log(this.x); } 
};

o.y(); // 12
```

You can access object's members via 2 notations:

- dot notation: `o.x`, `o,y`
- brackets notation: `o['x']`, `o['y']`

Note, in the second approach you must provide a string, which means
`var name = 'x'; o[name]` will work, while `o[x]` will not.

This is valid for arrays as well:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr[0] // 'a'
arr['0'] // 'a'
Object.keys(arr) // ['0', '1', '2']
```

however, you can not do `arr.0`

Now, regarding your problem:
`arr['first', 'second']` is equivalent with `arr['second']` because you use the comma operator which evaluates each expression, from left to right, and returns the value of the most right one.
eg: `1, alert(0), 5` gives you `5`

Answer (score 3):

It's not an array but an object, but the first problem is actually interesting.

Getting object properties using `[]` notations means you need to pass a key - it may look like an array literal, but it isn't.

What you put in the square brackets is a statement.

For example you could do something like this: `arr[ condition ? 'first' : 'second' ]` - the statement is parsed and its return value is passed as the key.

In `arr['first', 'second']` the inner statement can be read as `('first', 'second')` which returns `second`, because in JS a statement consisting of many of expressions returns the value of the last one, for example `(x=2, 4)` returns `4`.

It also sheds some light on `object.child` vs. `object['child']`. In the first example you need to use an actual key, while in the second one you pass a statement; in this case the statement evaluates to string, but it could be a variable name, or anything that would evaluate to something that can be used as a key (string or number).